# What am I doing wrong here? I am having an error using sklearn LabelEncoder()

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is my code and the error: The columns unique values for sex are: male,female and Embarked are: S,C,Q,nan.

Code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
def l_e(df):
    df['Embarked']= label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Embarked'])
    df['Sex']= label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Sex'])
train = l_e(train)
test = l_e(test)

train
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/4261505711.py in <module>
      3 def l_e(df):
      4     df['Sex']= label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Sex'])
----> 5 train = l_e(train)
      6 test = l_e(test)
      7 

/tmp/ipykernel_17/4261505711.py in l_e(df)
      2 label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
      3 def l_e(df):
----> 4     df['Sex']= label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Sex'])
      5 train = l_e(train)
      6 test = l_e(test)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you get the same error if you use `None[0]` - so problem is `df = None`, and this means `train = None` (and maybe `test = None`). Where do you create `train` ? maybe you assign value from function which doesn't use `return value` - so it automatically uses `return None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes from your variable being `None`. Make sure that `train` and `test` actually contain a DataFrame.

Also, note that your function doesn't return anything, so you need to apply it to the two dataframes directly, since they will be modified inside of the function, in place:

```py
l_e(train)
l_e(test)
```

However, it seems unlikely that you want to use the same `LabelEncoder` for the two features `Embarked` and `Sex`. You should have one encode per feature. Furthermore, you are using `fit_transform` on both the train and test set, which is also probably not what you want to do, because that means the encodings of the labels might be different between train and test. Overall, I suggest you don't actually use a function, but rewrite your code like this:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing
label_encoder_embarked = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_sex = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

# Preprocessing
train['Embarked'] = label_encoder_embarked.fit_transform(train['Embarked'])
train['Sex'] = label_encoder_sex.fit_transform(train['Sex'])

test['Embarked'] = label_encoder_embarked.transform(test['Embarked'])
test['Sex'] = label_encoder_sex.fit_transform(test['Sex'])
```

Comment: No, you would get a different error if the variable did not exist.

Comment: you get the same error if you use `None[0]` - so problem is `df = None`

Comment: Hmm right! I'll edit my answer, but the rest should still be valid

Answer (score 0):

According to [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.fit_transform) you should pass an array-like of shape (n_samples,) to `fit_transform()` method, so `df['Embarked']` should match the required type. The error message says that the passed argument is of type `None`.

What is the `train` variable that you are passing to `l_f` function?

In addition, your `l_e` function doesn't return anything, so it imiplicitly returns `None` which will raise another exception in line `test = l_e(test)`.